# Media Query with ID Selector getting 'expected LBRACE' syntax error

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to update some CSS for mobile only but keep getting the following syntax error: Expected LBRACE at Line 17 Col 1 (which refers to the #logo line)

```
@media {max-width: 979px)
#logo { 
left: 50%;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

When I edit the CSS in developer tools, it works fine, but as soon as I place it in my CSS child it doesn't work.

Comment: you have syntax error
`@media {max-width: 979px)`
need to be
`@media (max-width: 979px)`

Comment: ^ the syntax should be `@media (max-width: 970px) { #logo { *styles here* } }`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for a media query is:

```css
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  #logo {
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

For reference, see [Using Media Queries @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

> The @media CSS at-rule associates a set of nested statements, in a CSS block that is delimited by curly braces, with a condition defined by a media query.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. Syntax error is gone, but my changes do not appear on front end. Checking the code, my changes have come up in the CSS but the media query is referencing a 404 error instead of my bootstrap-responsive.css - any idea why this would be happening? I am working from a child theme.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the media query is referencing a 404 error instead of my bootstrap-responsive.css". Are you getting a 404 error for that CSS file? Do you mind providing a link to your page?

Comment: Sure, it's http://66.147.244.244/~gracepar/
I'm new to CSS... My terminology may be incorrect but if you inspect the logo element in mobile mode, you'll notice the @media (max-width: 979px) { #logo { section is repeated twice, the 2nd time it has a 404 in the associated CSS file that the media query is referencing. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any 404 errors. Also, I'm not sure how the media query references a CSS file. It does seem like your CSS styles and media queries are defined in several places (style.css, bootstrap.css, and in-page style tags) and might conflict each other. You might benefit from organizing them more consistently. However, it looks like the page works correctly. Is there something specific that's going wrong with the logo?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to centre the logo on mobile. Currently it floats right.
Here's a screenshot of the issue I am seeing: 
http://i65.tinypic.com/if68oh.jpg

Comment: I was able to to fix the issue. The 404 error I can't work out but it happened when I used the 'custom css' field in WordPress CMS. I tried updating the child style.css theme directly via FTP and use the !important rule on my float value to get it to override bootstrap-responsive.css value for this. 
If you know of a better way to do things though, I'd be glad to hear it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax error

```
@media {max-width: 979px)
```

need to be

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
```